# Review scripts which are older than 3 months and in the last 30 days

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I'm try to run a query that will allow me to see where we have scripts running that are older than 3 months old over the last 30 days delivery, so we know they need to be updated. 
I have been able to build the query to show me all the scripts and their last regen dates (with specific dates put in) but can't work out;

1. How to look at only the last 30 days data.
2. How to see only the scripts where the date_regen column is older than 3 months from today's date - From the last 30 days data that I'm reviewing.

EXAMPLE TABLE

```
visit_datetime      | client | script     |    date_regen          |
2019/10/04 03:32:51 | 1      | script1    |   2019-09-17 13:12:01  |
2019/09/27 03:32:52 | 2      | script2    |   2019-07-18 09:44:02  |
2019/10/06 03:32:50 | 3      | script3    |   2019-03-18 14:08:02  |
2019/10/02 06:28:24 | 4      | script6    |   2019-09-11 10:02:01  |
2019/03/01 06:28:24 | 5      | script7    |   2019-02-11 10:02:01  |
```

The below examples haven't been able to get me what I need. My idea was that I would get the current date (using now()) and then knowing that, look at all data in the last 30 days. 
After that I would then WHERE month,-3 (so date_regen 3 months+ old from the current date. 
However I can't get it to work. I also looked at trying to do -days but that also had no success.

```
-- WHERE MONTH = MONTH(now()) AND YEAR = YEAR(now())
-- WHERE date_regen <= DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE())
-- WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, date_regen, GetDate()) >= 3
```

Code I am currently using to get the table

```
SELECT split_part(js,'#',1) AS script,
date_regen,
client
FROM table
WHERE YEAR=2019 AND MONTH=10 AND DAY = 01 (This where is irrelevant as I would need to use now() but I don't know what replaces "YEAR/MONTH/DAY ="
GROUP BY script,date_regen,client
ORDER BY client DESC;
```

END GOAL
I should only see client 3 as clients 1+2+4 have tags where the date_regen is in the last 3 months, and client 5 has a visit_datetime out of the 30 limit.

```
visit_datetime      | client | script  |   date_regen           |
2019/10/06 03:32:50 | 3      | script3 |   2019-03-18 14:08:02  |
```

Comment: What is a "script" in your data?

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry for the vagueness. A script in this instance is the column "js2" which is a long string I've broken down. I'll edit my post to be a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

I think you want simple filtering:

```
select t.*
from t
where visit_datetime >= current_timestamp - interval 30 day and
      date_regen < add_months(current_timestamp, -3)
```

Comment: adding this to the query returned 0 rows. I'll take your suggestion and see if it works independent from the rest of the query to get the result.